# How can I filter information ordering by two different factors on SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, filter

I have the three following tables:

```
create table Person (

    id int,
    popularity int,
    primary key (id)
);

create table Movie (

    id int,
    year int,
    primary key (id)
);

create table Person_Movie (

    id_person int,
    id_movie int,
    primary key (id_person, id_movie),
    foreign key (id_person) references Person (id_person),
    foreign key (id_movie) references Movie (id_movie)
);
```

I want to execute a `SELECT` to check which person has the higher number of `popularity` BUT has but has participated in less movies.

How can I do this?

To check the most popular person I'd execute this:

```
select P.id from Person as P, Movie as M, Person_Movie as PM
where P.id = PM.id and PM.id = M.id
group by (P.id)
order by popularity;
```

And, if I am correct, to check the person that has participated in less movies I'd execute this:

```
select P.id from Person as P, Movie as M, Person_Movie as PM
where P.id = PM.id and PM.id = M.id
group by (P.id)
order by count(M.id);
```

But, how can I filter the two cases in one `SELECT`?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I'm using MySQL.

Also I'll provide an example of what I'm trying to get:

Table Person

```
id      popularity
-------------------
1          50
2          35
3          120
4          45
```

Table Movie

```
id        year
----------------
1         1999
2         2014
3         1969
4         1977
5         2019
```

Table Person_Movie

```
id_person       id_movie
--------------------------
    1              1
    2              4
    2              5
    3              3
    4              1
    4              2
```

So, given this example, the output I would like to get is:

```
id_person
----------
    3
```

Because both persons with id `1` and `3` have participated in just ONE movie, but person with id `3` has the higher number of popularity.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would help.  Also, learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Learn how to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
select P.id from Person as P, Movie as M, Person_Movie as PM
where P.id = PM.id and PM.id = M.id
group by (P.id)
order by max(popularity),count(M.id);
```

This would sort your results by the count of movies if multiple people have the same popularity. If you want only the first row, you can use a top 1. Hope this helps.

Edit:

Based on the sample cases, it looks like the first priority of sorting should go to count:

```
select P.id from Person as P, Movie as M, Person_Movie as PM
where P.id = PM.id and PM.id = M.id
group by (P.id)
order by count(M.id),max(Popularity) desc;
```

Comment: That is what I was searching for, thanks. Does the order of the conditions on the `order by` clause have any hierarchy? Which one predominates?

Comment: Right now popularity takes the priority since it is mentioned first. Count(ID) comes into the picture only when there are multiple IDs with the same popularity

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to give precedence to the number of movies as the first expression in the ORDER BY, and then use popularity to break ties. Here's a query with an ORDER BY clause that accomplishes that:

```
SELECT TOP 1 id
FROM Person
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Person_Movie WHERE id_person = Person.id) ASC, 
    popularity DESC
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b58d6/1) based on your sample data.

Comment: Please, could you explain what's the last line doing? (after `ORDER BY popularity DESC` )

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your desired output, I assume you want to select the people who participated in the lowest number of movies out of the ones who are the most popular. (I assume popularity is your first priority)
Then the following query might work in MySQL

```
select A.id  
from (select id from Person where popularity=(select max(popularity) from Person)) A, Person_Movie B
where A.id = B.id 
group by A.id
order by count(*)
```

The first subquery returns the most popular people and then I tried to sort them by the number of movies they attended. (if you need only a single result you can add a `LIMIT 1` in the end)